# Whatever hover not working IE6 and IE7

Tags: css, menu, hover, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

Below is the css for my menu

```
#menu
{
 position: absolute;
 left: 170px;
 top: 92px;
 background: #336699;
 float: left;
 z-index:50;
}

#menu ul
{
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 9em;
 float: left;
}

#menu a, #menu h2
{
 font: bold 11px/20px arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
 display: block;
 border-top-width: 1px;
 border-bottom-width: 1px;
 border-left-width: 1px;
 border-right-width: 1px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #ccc #888 #555 #bbb;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 4px 3px;
}

#menu h2
{
 color: #fff;
 background: #336699;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 border-top-width: 0px;
 border-bottom-width: 0px;
 border-left-width: 1px;
 border-right-width: 1px;
}

#menu a
{
 color: #fff;
 background: #79A3CF;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#menu a:hover
{
 color: #a00;
 background: #fff;
}

#menu li
{
 position: relative;
}

#menu li ul li
{
 position: relative;
 width: 12em;
}

#menu ul ul
{
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 500;
}

#menu ul ul ul
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 100%;
}

div#menu ul ul, div#menu ul li:hover ul ul, div#menu ul ul li:hover ul ul
{
 display: none;
}



div#menu ul li:hover ul, div#menu ul ul li:hover ul, div#menu ul ul ul li:hover ul
{
 display: block;
}
```

---

Here is my html design for the menu. It is a horizontal menu with dropdown submenus

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><h2>Computers</h2>
        <ul>
             <li>subitem
                  <ul><li>subitems</li>
             </li>
             <li>submitem</li>
             <li>submitem</li>
      </li>
     <li><h2>Network</h2>
                 <ul><li>subitems</li>
     </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

I am using the minified version of the whatever hover script. Checked few posts here on this issue but couldn't solve the problem. The submenus are not appearing on IE6 and IE7. I trid adding

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
```

but no results...

Comment: First step: Fix how the CSS is displayed here, so it has better formatting and it's easier for us to read. Do the same to that as you did for the HTML: Paste it as normal, select the text, hit the `code` button above the editor (shows as little 1's and 0's)

Comment: Maybe add a link to the whatever hover script - I presume a lot of people are not familiar with it.

Comment: http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is poorly formed. ** indicates additions.

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><h2>Computers</h2>
        <ul>
             <li>subitem
                  <ul><li>subitems</li>**</ul>**
             </li>
             <li>submitem</li>
             <li>submitem</li>
     **</ul>**
      </li>

     <li><h2>Network</h2>
                 <ul><li>subitems</li>**</ul>**
     </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Presumably the closing `</ul>` (to close the nested `ul`) tag.

Answer (score 0):

One good way to check for poorly formed html and other html problems is to validate your html in the w3c validator [here](http://validator.w3.org/).By using the validator to make sure my html is compliant, I can usually weed out browser discrepancies issues pretty easily.